# Android - Handle app crash

Tags: android, crash

I'm wondering if there is anyway to handle an application crash. By that, I mean if we can detect a crash and when it occurs save some data, because I need to save some values into a SharedPreference if the application crashes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an open-source project for reporting or handling the crash report. try this link
[ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)

Comment: you can save them anywhere google docs, or sqlite database, or simple text file. The all ways are described on that site.http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup?tm=6

Comment: is it library to use within android app or external support?

Comment: this is so called library, from which you can keep track of your crash reports which are unexpected( out of scope of try-catch block) errors. like issue tracker. It automatically posts the report to email,text file or database. Ofcourse, it is used within android app. you can use it in your application.

Comment: I also detected that one can use UncaughtExceptionHandler in MainActivity in order to get the same results.

Comment: yes, of course, you can us uncaughtexceptionhandler, you can implement it in class and can handle errors.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Try...Catch...finally block to Catch Exception and when Exception occurs finally block content definitely works even exception handled or not.